# Why does a struct referring to str with shorter lifetime compile in Rust?

Tags: rust

So I am trying to test if I understand lifetimes, and wanted to create a scenario that would fail at compile time. The code I came up with is below:

```
#[test]
fn lifetime() {

    struct Identity<'a> {
        first_name: &'a str
    }
    
    let name: Identity;

    {
        let first: &str = "hello";

        name = Identity {
            first_name: first
        };
    }

    println!("{}", name.first_name);
}
```

the reasoning is that instance of `Identity` should live as long as what `first_name` refrences.

Then in the code I create `let first: &str = "hello"` with a smaller scope, set it to `let name: Identity;` and then after `first` should have gone out of scope, I then attempted to print `name.first_name`. I was expecting this not to compile,, but it compile fine.

What am I missing in my understanding of how lifetimes work and why did this compile?

#Edit

updating the code to have this instead made the compilation fail:

```
        let string = String::from("hello");
        let first: &str = string.as_str();
```

still curious to know why the original code worked.

Comment: I think you moved `first` into `first_name` so now `name` owns the `&str`? I'm not a rustacean so I'm probably babbling nonsense.

Comment: hmm not sure if that is the case. `first_name` is still of type `&str` so not sure if `first` could have been moved into it, as that means `first_name` will now be of type `String`

Comment: References can be moved just like anything else. In this case, the string slice reference stored in `first` has the `'static` lifetime, since it references a literal value.

Comment: @PitaJ "the string slice reference stored in first has the 'static lifetime, since it references a literal value" I think that is the crux of it and why it works.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because you move `first` into `name`. `first` references `'static` data (a special lifetime that lives for the entirety of a program), a literal string in this case which can never go out of scope.

To make your test fail to compile, try referencing data that *will* go out of scope:

```
#[test]
fn lifetime() {
    struct Identity<'a> {
        first_name: &'a str
    }
    
    let name: Identity;

    {
        let first: String = String::from("hello");

        name = Identity {
            first_name: &first,
        };
        // `first` will go out of scope here and any references to it
        // (like `&first` within `name`) will become invalid.
    }

    // `first` has been dropped so you can't reference it anymore here:
    println!("{}", name.first_name);
}
```

Comment: “ Because you move first into name” is that a move or just a normal copy?

Comment: @dade Because `&T` is `Copy` it is actually a copy. You could still access the original in its scope.

Answer (score 2):

Variable `first` is an alias to a string literal with static lifetime. Therefore, the `let first: &str = "hello";` has a hidden lifetime specifier "static" and it is equivalent to:

```
let first: &'static str = "hello";
```

That enables the variable `name` to have a lifetime anything up to static. However, it is lifetime is determined by the outer scope, which is shorter but long enough to enable that `println` statement.